# Solve/Simplify an Equation that involves multiple variables for one variable e.g. x

Tags: equation-solving

I am new at Mathematica and have very basic knowledge about it. I want to solve the following equation for variable `x` in Mathemtica.

`x*N*[(d/v)*2^((k+L)/x) - (d/v)*2^(L/x) +2^(L/x)-1] - P*d = 0` This Equation involves seven variables namely, `x, N, d, v, L, k, P`. Please Help me solve this equation. Thanks

Comment: A transcendental equation like that will often not have an explicit solution; you will have to be content with numerics.

Comment: Also, `N` is a reserved symbol, brackets should be replaced by parentheses, and `Set` should be replaced by `Equal`.  Even with these corrections, `Solve` cannot handle this transcendental equation, as J.M. previously commented.  Remember that Mathematica only applies known solution methods.  It does not create new ones.